# Buy Now Paypal button add different postage for Europe and USA

Tags: paypal

I am selling just one type of item on a website and I am using the Buy Now button from Paypal .. is there a way to change the postage cost for overseas customers? I have seen in Paypal you can change the postage depending on the value of the sale (for more than one item) but I can't see how to change the postage for overseas? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you 
Dawnyanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your PayPal account you can update the shipping methods to include international shipping methods. Just choose the option for International Shipping Methods.

From PayPal Documentation:

You can use PayPal to calculate shipping costs automatically on your website.

Here's how to set up shipping profile calculations:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click the Business profile  con beside the "Log out" button and select
3. Profile and settings.
4. Click Selling tools.
5. Click Update beside "Shipping calculations."
6. Click Start to set up your shipping region.
7. Set up one or more shipping methods and click Continue.
8. Enter your shipping information and click Create Another or Continue.
9. Review your information and click Save Shipping Methods. 
   **Note:** 
   Shipping rates depend on order amount, order weight, or item quantity. You can choose rates based on a fixed amount or a percentage. 
   You will not be able to use the PayPal Profile Shipping Calculator with Express Checkout and PayPal Payments Pro accounts. This functionality can only be used with PayPal Payments Standard accounts. 
   If your shipping methods require more customization, you may want to integrate PayPal with a third-party application. Go to our Developer Network at https://developer.paypal.com/ for information on integrating a third-party shopping cart or shipping application. 
   **Note:** Customers with a Personal account will need to upgrade to a Business account for this feature.

[Setting Up Shipping Methods](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9EG00Y5H) 
[image: Shipping Methods View]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help pp_MSI_Jenn I really appreciate it .. so pleased I can do this now! Thanks again! Dawn

Comment: HI pp_MSI_Jenn how do add a 'vote' sorry I am new to stackoverflow!

Comment: Here the link in Stack that gives instructions on how to accept or deny an answer. [How to Respond to Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: This information is no longer up to date, could you supply new information?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Generate an unregistered payment button on the fly**

One way is to have kind of **toggle buttons** on your site and let the user select the right region. (e.g. 'Italy', 'Europe', 'World'). This can be achieved through radio buttons or a select list. Set the shipping value for each of the regions.
With few **conditional coding**, like PHP `if {} elseif {} else {}`, **you can generate a payment link on the fly, with the correct price for the shipment**. Such payment link will look like:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=ABCDEFGHIJKL&item_name=Your%20product%20name&item_number=P123&amount=10.00&currency_code=GBP&shipping=15.00
```

Notice the `shipping` parameter at the end of the URL.
You can use all PayPal Payment Standard variables for your link.

Because the button is not registered at PayPal, a buyer could edit the URL and modify the amount for the product, as well as the shipping cost.

So after receiving a payment, you will have to do a few things:

1. Log in your PayPal account to check that you well received the payment and not a fake email.
2. Check that the amount paid is well the one of your product, and was not tampered by the buyer.
3. Check that the shipping cost paid is the correct one for the region where you have to send the item.
   If you have a low volume of sales, this method works perfectly.

**Method 2: Consider shipment as a product and use "Add to cart" buttons**

1. In PayPal, create a "Shipment" product with priced options, one per region.
2. Instead of "Buy now" buttons, use "Add to cart" for both your product and your "Shipment" pseudo-product.
3. On your website, make it clear for your visitors that after adding your product  to the hosted PayPal cart, they will have to click the "Continue shopping" and select the Shipment product on your site, so that it is added to the cart.

This second method has the benefit of using buttons that if registered at PayPal cannot be tampered.
The drawback is that the purchase process is more complicated for your buyers, and there is a risk they miss to add the shipment product to the cart.

**Method 3: include the shipping costs in a product with priced options**

Set a "Buy now" payment button with priced options (one per shipping region) and include the shipping price in you product price (i.e. product with "free" shipping).

**Which is better?**

By personal choice, I only used methods 1 and 2.

From my experience, both work, with casual errors from buyers if using method 2. Your terms and conditions and customer service will solve these cases.

Method 1 is my prefered one in most situations.

Method 3 would be the easiest to implement. You can give the details concerning the real product price and the shipping costs or your site and explain what all costs are summed for the payment step.